# How to insert attribute to json string in mysql?

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-json

I had a json string in mysql database like following.

```
{"name":"Georg","position":"Manager"}
```

I need to add another attribute like "date_of_birth":"1989-06-08"

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [JSON_INSERT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-insert) function:

```sql
SELECT JSON_INSERT(@`json`, '$.date_of_birth', '1989-06-08');
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3b67994b188c0383416ce8242d774c61).

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a replace() function on the json string

```
select  REPLACE ( column_name, "}",  ', "date_of_birth":"1989-06-08"}')
from my_table
```

or for update  the value in you table

```
UPDATE my_table
SET column_name = REPLACE ( column_name, "}",  ', "date_of_birth":"1989-06-08"}')
```